# Highcharts Export Server - Getting a blank chart

Tags: javascript, post, highcharts, server, export

I'm developing an app in which I use Highcharts. At some point I want to export the chart and get the PNG url.

To do so, I've tried using the Highcharts' export server and it returns me an URL, but when I try to browse it I get an empty chart.

```
var data = {
    options: JSON.stringify(chart.options),
    filename: chart.exporting.filename,
    type: 'image/png',
    async: true
};
var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com';

$.post(exportUrl, data, function(data){
    var url = exportUrl + data;
};
```

Here is the `chart.options` that I try to send to the export server.[(See also a screenshot of my chart, don't know if it will make it clearer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R55eO.png)

```
   {…}
    ​
    chart: Object { styledMode: false, borderRadius: 0, colorCount: 10, … }
    ​
    colors: Array(10) [ "#7cb5ec", "#434348", "#90ed7d", … ]
    ​
    credits: Object { enabled: true, href: "https://www.highcharts.com?credits", text: "Highcharts.com", … }
    ​
    exporting: Object { type: "image/png", url: "https://export.highcharts.com/", printMaxWidth: 780, … }
    ​
    global: Object {  }
    ​
    labels: Object { style: {…} }
    ​
    lang: Object { loading: "Loading...", decimalPoint: ".", resetZoom: "Reset zoom", … }
    ​
    legend: Object { enabled: true, align: "right", alignColumns: true, … }
    ​
    loading: Object { labelStyle: {…}, style: {…} }
    ​
    navigation: Object { buttonOptions: {…}, menuStyle: {…}, menuItemStyle: {…}, … }
    ​
    plotOptions: Object { line: {…}, area: {…}, spline: {…}, … }
    ​
    responsive: Object { rules: (1) […] }
    ​
    series: undefined
    ​
    subtitle: Object { style: {…}, align: "center", widthAdjust: -44, … }
    ​
    symbols: Array(5) [ "circle", "diamond", "square", … ]
    ​
    time: Object {  }
    ​
    title: Object { align: "center", margin: 15, widthAdjust: -44, … }
    ​
    tooltip: Object { enabled: true, animation: true, borderRadius: 3, … }
    ​
    xAxis: Array [ {…} ]
    ​
    yAxis: Array(14) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
    ​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    4:1082:11
```

​

I was expecting the variable "url" to get me the chart, but it was a blank chart.
(I have been following the second method given here https://gist.github.com/philfreo/0a4d899de4257e08a000).
I was thinking the error might be coming from the "options" part, but I didn't know what to put instead.

Comment: Since the error probably is in the `chart.options` its almost impossible to guess the problem. In general this method should work fine. Do you have any example `options` where you can demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure that I get the question.There are a lot of informations in chart.options, do you want me to show you the entire chart.options ?

Comment: Well, yes. Because if I do your example code with a simple "hello world" it works, so need to see what is causing it in your `options`.

Comment: I see you've added some more code. The screenshot is of how your chart actually is, while you get a blank image when using the export server, right? See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/tq97pa4c/) of simple hello world with pretty much your code and simple chart. Notice anything different?

Comment: I finally found it ! It is my chart.options.series which causes the problem. It is undefined and the informations of my series are stored in chart.series.

Comment: Now I get another problem. I had to define my chart.options.series, to do so I used the replacer parameter in the JSON.stringify, and when I sent it to the export server, I got this error : Chart input data error. TypeError : null is not an object (evaluating 'c[k].type'). My data object is not null. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `chart.options` you should use `chart.userOptions`. Check it and let me know if it helped you.

```
var data = {
    options: JSON.stringify(chart.userOptions),
    filename: chart.exporting.filename,
    type: 'image/png',
    async: true
};
var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com';

$.post(exportUrl, data, function(data){
    var url = exportUrl + data;
};
```

Comment: I checked it and it didn't work. However, I managed to solve it by defining the chart.options.series.